# Why qt have better performance when render svg file in opengl than in native

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, svg

Sorry if it sounds stupid. I'm new to QT world.

I'm running SVG Viewer Example from [QT official website](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-svgviewer-example.html). And I find out that the performance is very different in Native mode and OpenGL mode.

Basically the different of this two mode is that. In native mode, its viewport is 
a QWidget; in OpenGl mode, its viewport is a QGLWidget.

**My question is what leads to the performance difference?** Is there any online document about this?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The performance is not necessarily different, but the **CPU usage** is. That is because OpenGL moves the **calculations onto the GPU**.

You can think of OpenGL basically as an API for programming the GPU.

When you switch to "Native", all **calculations** like the rasterization of the SVG data is **done on the CPU**, which is what you can see in the Task Manager.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to me!

Comment: This is quite insightful: the CPU usage gets lower when using OpenGL, but this tells us nothing about performance. The latter will depend on how the OpenGL paint engine backend behaves on the particular SVG-specific workload when compared to raster backend running on the CPU. It might potentially perform worse in some cases, e.g. on some mobile GPUs.